# ¿Cómo usar javascript desde php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, jquery-ui

Tengo el siguiente valor en un html en la vista laravel 
, el cual esta en el siguiente formulario

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('savecheckin')}}">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                          </button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Realizar Checkin</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <input id="idbookcheck" name="idbook"> 
                           <!--input id="codigobook" name="codigobook"--> 
                           <h5>¿Está seguro que desea hacer el checkin de la reserva Num <span id="reservacode"> </span> que tiene como titular
                              <span id="titular"></span>?</h5>
                        </div>   

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-default">
                          <input type="submit" value="Hacer checkin" class="btn btn-success" name="checkin">                                                      
                         </div>
```

Pero quiero capturar el valor que tiene ese input con jquery para enviarlo a un post de un formulario, como capturo el valor del input expuesto con javascript para enviarlo por post en laravel

Answer (score 1):

```js
function cargaDatos() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/routeCualquieraLaravel',
            data: {
                valor_1: $("#idbookcheck").val(),
                /* Aquí manda todos los input que gustes el .val() obtiene
                  el valor que contiene ese campo del input con el id que 
                  tu le asignaste */
                valor_n: $("#idbookcheckN").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert('Enviaré mis datos va.');
            },
            success: function (respuesta) {
                /*Esta respuesta te sugiero la mandes en JSON desde el 
                  Controlador*/
                alert('Soy la V ... ' + respuesta);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('ALV ocurrió un error PTM ' + jqXHR.responseText )
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="cargaDatos()">Enviame</button>
```

Hola, primero que nada creo que quieres obtener los valores de tus input al hacer el envió con tu formulario para hacer alguna consulta, yo optaría por que tenga la acción el boton de la siguiente forma:

Tienes que entender la naturaleza de tu DOM en muchas ocasiones abusamos de muchas malas practicas y con tal de que funcione pegamos código pero no debe ser así. Saludos.